# Can't get a value from $http promise and then() code not executed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angularjs-service, angular-promise

I already had a problem with `$http` service in the past which I resolved by creating a service to handle my requests (for those who are interested, here's the link of the answer which helped me, the EDIT part : [creating a service for $http request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38741190/6619443) ).

The problem now is that this solution seems inefficient to handle bigger `$http` requests. In the previous one, I only assigned a word that were returned by the request to a `$scope` value. Now, what is returned is a whole configuration in JSON format (that I also want to store in the `$scope`).

I understand the concept of promises, the fact that the value returned by `$http` is a null string until the response comes, and that it could take time. But here, the configuration is not that long, and I never seem to get an answer ; I display the variable that recieves the value on the view and it doesn't change when the function is called.

Here's the code :

#### View

```
...
<div>
    {{loadedConfig}} 
</div>
<button ng-click="loadconfig()">load</button>
```

#### Controller

```
app.controller('ConfigurationCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, configloader) {
    ...
    $scope.loadedConfig = 'noconfig'
    $scope.loadconfig = function() {
        configloader.load().then(function (response) {
            $scope.loadedConfig = response.data;
        });
    };
```

#### Factory

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('configloader', configloaderFactory);

function configloaderFactory($http) {

   var service = {
      load: load
   }

   return service;

   function load() {
      return $http.get('url/config');
   }
}
```

If I call a 'lesser weighted request', this works without a problem. I also tried other methods to make this call but in every case it didn't work... (with `$q.deferred`, with success()/error(),  or with a custom `sleep()` function)

Is the code in the `then` supposed to execute when I get the response ? (I assume it is, but it never does).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try return the `promise` in you factory, somthing like :

```
function load() {
     var promise =   $http.get('url/config').then(function(response){
     return response.data;     
     }, function(err){
       //error     
       return err;
     });
     return promise;
   }
```

Comment: It's not working but now I have a hint on the problem, the code gave me this error : "angular.js:13708 SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 155"
What does it mean ? Is angular trying to analyze the JSON ? Why doesnt it just diplay the config as it is ?

Comment: So it is working, my code works, just google the error code, I am sure you will find out. please mark the answer as correct.

Comment: also I think that you should 1.check the response is a vaild json 2.parse it corrctly, try using transformResponse, read about it and then use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('configloader', configloaderFactory);

function configloaderFactory($http) {

   var service = {
      load: load
   }

   return service;

   function load() {
      return $http.get('url/config')
      .then(requestSuccessful)
      .catch(requestFailed)
   }

   function requestSuccessful(response) {
        return response.data;
    }

   function requestFailed(error) {
        console.log('Fail', error.data)
    }

}
```

Comment: Didn't work either, running it step by step shows that it doesnt enter the requestSuccessful() function

Comment: Added catching failed request. What error is catched?

Comment: The error is : 'Fail undefined' ... Thanks for helping me though

Comment: But ! I also noticed this error in the console :
'angular.js:13708 SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 155'
Could it come from there ? Isn't the JSON supposed to comport as text string and just be displayed as it is ? (It looks like angular is trying to analyze it in some way)

Answer (score 0):

Since this is related to long (bigger) request, consider changing your code and use timeout:

```
return $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'url/config',
    timeout: 1 * 60 * 1000    // timeout of 1 minute
});
```

Comment: Didn't work either. Is the timeout supposed to stop the execution of the application ? It didn't stop it